# Safely pass a dynamic column name into an ActiveRecord query with a Postgres cast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I do a lot of time without date querying in my app, and I would like to abstract some of the queries away.

So say I have a model with a `DateTime` `starts_at` field:

```
Shift.where('starts_at::time > ?', '20:31:00.00')
-> SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE (starts_at::time > '20:31:00.00')
```

This correctly returns all of the 'starts_at' values greater than the time 20:31.

I want to dynamically pass in the column name into the query, so I can do something like:

```
Shift.where('? > ?', "#{column_name}::time", '20:31:00.00').
-> SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE ('starts_at::time' > '20:31:00.00')
```

In this example, this does not work as the search executes `starts_at::time` as a string, not as a column with the `time` cast.

How can I safely pass in `column_name` into a query with the `::time` cast? While this will not accept user input, I would still like to ensure SQL injection is accounted for.

Comment: you try with a temp var like `query_text = " start_at > ?"` and then use `Shift.where( query_text , '20:31:00.00')`?

Comment: @inye But the problem is that he doesn't necessarily know that `column_name` is `'start_at'`, the column name could, in theory, come in as `'pancakes house'` so it needs to be quoted/escaped before it can be sent to the database.

Comment: and when you know the `column_name`? maybe you can have some `if else` to assign `query_text`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is more complicated than you might think at first because identifiers (column names, table names, ...) and values (`'pancakes'`, `6`, ...) are very different things in SQL that have different quoting rules and even quote characters (single quotes for strings, double quotes for identifiers in standard SQL, backticks for identifiers in MySQL, brackets for identifiers in SQL-Server, ...). If you think of identifiers like Ruby variable names and values like, well, literal Ruby values then you can start to see the difference.

When you say this:

```
where('? > ?', ...)
```

both placeholders will be treated as values (not identifiers) and quoted as such. Why is this? ActiveRecord has no way of knowing which `?` should be an identifier (such as the `created_at` column name) and which should be a value (such as `20:31:00.00`).

The database connection does have a method specifically for quoting column names though:

```
> puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name('pancakes')
"pancakes"
=> nil
```

so you can say things like:

```
quoted_column = Shift.connection.quote_column_name(column_name)
Shift.where("#{quoted_name}::time > ?", '20:31:00.00')
```

This is a little unpleasant because we recoil (or at least we should) at using string interpolation to build SQL. However, `quote_column_name` will take care of anything dodgy or unsafe in `column_name` so this isn't actually dangerous.

You could also say:

```
quoted_column = "#{Shift.connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}::time"
Shift.where("#{quoted_name} > ?", '20:31:00.00')
```

if you didn't always need to cast the column name to a `time`. Or even:

```
clause = "#{Shift.connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}::time > ?"
Shift.where(clause, '20:31:00.00')
```

You could also use [`extract` or one of the other date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) instead of a typecast but you'd still be left with the quoting problem and the somewhat cringeworthy `quote_column_name` call.

Another option would be to whitelist `column_name` so that only specific valid values would be allowed. Then you could throw the safe `column_name` right into the query:

```
if(!in_the_whitelist(column_name))
  # Throw a tantrum, hissy fit, or complain in your preferred fashion
end
Shift.where("#{column_name} > ?", '20:31:00.00')
```

This should be fine as long as you don't have any funky column names like `"gotta have some breakfast"` or similar things that always need to be properly quoted. You could even use `Shift.column_names` or `Shift.columns` to build your whitelist.

Using both a whitelist and then `quote_column_name` would probably be the safest but the `quote_column_name` method should be sufficient.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It feels a bit wrong to me with the interpolation, even though it is safe, but best of the bad solutions!

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Great solution, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use this small solution, taking advantage of Rails column naming conventions:

```
  scope :field_before_and_on_date, -> (field, time) do
    column_name = field.to_s.parameterize.underscore
    where("#{column_name} <= ?", time.end_of_day)
  end

# Takes advantage of:
> "); and delete everything(); stuff(".parameterize.underscore
=> "and_delete_everything_stuff"
```

It's limited but the concept would work for a type cast too.

Comment: quote_column_name turns it into a string `> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name("); and delete everything(); stuff(") # => "\"); and delete everything(); stuff(\""`